# Solve: $y''=(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}$ / $y(1)=\frac 15, y'(1)=\frac 34$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, differential

My attempt:

$y''=(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}$

$\displaystyle\implies \frac {y''}{(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}}=1$

$\displaystyle\implies \int_{}^{} \frac {y''}{(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}} dx=x+c$

$\displaystyle\implies \int\limits_{}^{}\frac{1}{(1+u^2)\sqrt{1+u^2}}du=x+c,$ where $  u=y'$

$\displaystyle\implies \int\limits_{}^{}\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{(1+u^2)^2}du=x+c$

I am stuck here, is my approach correct and can solve the problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is still ugly, but why not let $p = y'$, so $p'=y''$ to clean things up? We get $$p' = (1 + p^2)^{3/2}, ~~p(1) = y'(1) = 3/4$$ Solve for $p$ and then use $y' = p$ to find $y$.

Comment: The term $1+u^2$ screams for a trig substitution.

Answer (score 1):

You have found that

$\displaystyle\int\frac{du}{(1+u^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=x+c$

Let $u=\tan\theta$ , therefore $du=\sec^2\theta d\theta$

$\displaystyle\int\frac{\sec^2\theta  d\theta}{\sec^3\theta}=x+c$

$\displaystyle\int\cos\theta=x+c$

$\sin\theta=x+c$

$\displaystyle \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}=x+c$
where $u=y'$

We can find $c$ by the fact the $u(1)=\frac{3}{4}$
Solving we get

$\displaystyle \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}=x-\frac{2}{5}$

Now $u=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and then our integral becomes

$\displaystyle\int dy =\int \frac{x-\frac{2}{5}}{\sqrt{1-(x-\frac{2}{5}})^2}dx$

which can be easily solved using substitution.

The final answer would be

$(y-1)^2+(x-\frac{2}{5})^2=1$